# table view in DragonFireSDK

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008

I'm using DragonFireSDK to develop an iphone app in windows. Does any one knows how to create a table view using DragonFire SDK in visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

This may be late, but add an Image of a Editbox or something, and either use EditAdd(x, y, callback, id) or TextAdd(x,y,text,font). :)